# Borland C++ to Cygwin C++ : TThreads to pthreads?

Tags: c++, cygwin, pthreads, tthread, borland-c++

I'm working on a project that I need to eliminate all references to the Borland C++ compiler (why I'm doing this is not the question :) ) and have been relatively successful so far.

However, I have this class that extends TThreads, the Borland thread class. I would like to use pthreads instead but I'm not quite sure if pthreads can be extended.

If anyone has any useful tidbits about extending the pthread class or even converting from Borland to non-Borland I would be greatly appreciative!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to extend pthread? Or do you really just want a wrapper around a pthread?

A good reference for pthreads
https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Pthread

Comment: After looking at the link, I think I figured out what I really need: I'm going to create a pthread which calls the method(s) already created in the Borland class as part of the pthread. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: can you use boost. I know it have a lot of overhead in just getting it in. but i can do some amazing thing!!